# rectangle in a circle - find the length of diagonal

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me? I have no clue how to do it.

Problem: Rectangle ABCD lies in circle D with AB=6, and CE=4. What is the length of diagonal AC?

[image]

Comment: I take it $D$ is the centre.  Then $DB=10$ so $AC=10$.

Comment: This is a famous tricky problem.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\;AC=BD\;$ (the diagonals of a rectangle are of equal length), so the rectangle's diagonals equals the circle's radius, which is...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $D$ is the center of the circle:
Since $ABCD$ is a rectangle, then $CD=AB$. (Opposite sides of a rectangle are equal.)
Since $AB=6$, $CD=6$ and $DE$ is $DC+CE$, which is $6+4=10$.
$DB$ and $DE$ are both radii of circle $D$, so $DB=DE=10$.
And since $ABCD$ is a rectangle, then $AC=DB$. (Diagonals of a rectangle are equal.)
We know that $DB=10$, so $AC=DB=10$
**Answer: 10**.

Answer (score 0):

$AB+CE=DC+CE= BD$ (the radius of the circle) = $10$

Hence $AB+CE=DC+CE= AC = BD = 10$